# Exception while building a dictionary (Linq to SQL)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Well I am trying to build a dictionary using linq to SQL. Not sure how to pick distinct values using the below query. The idea to is fetch the instances of a title between a date.

```
    GolfitoDataContext db = new GolfitoDataContext();
    var dic = db.GetTable<History>()
            .Select(p => new { p.Title, p.Date }).Where(x => x.Date >= startDateFilter && x.Date <= endDateFilter)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Title, v => v.Date);
```

I get an exception that "An item with the same key has already been added."

I know its got to do with the "title" being repeated. But not sure how to apply the Distinct() method in the above condition to be able to build the dictionary. If I am doing something wrong, please correct me. Thanks!

Comment: What do you *want* to happen if you have the same title multiple times? Perhaps you want a lookup instead?

Comment: what if there are Titles more than once? For instance there are books that ARE different but have the SAME title and different dates. How would you distinct those?

Comment: I basically want title to instance mapping. If there are titles with same name, they should be considered as a single title. This way I will know all the instances(date) for a title or set of titles in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [MoreLinQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

```
var dic = db.GetTable<History>()
            .Select(p => new { p.Title, p.Date }).Where(x => x.Date >= startDateFilter && x.Date <= endDateFilter)
            .DistinctBy(x=>x.Title) 
            .AsEnumerable()
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Title, v => v.Date);
```

Comment: Q: Would distinct really work in this case if several different items have different titles?

Comment: One more question. I am able to retrieve only a single date value in the dictionary mapping, while I wanted all the instances. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: @Navyseal i didn't get your question. sample input and expected output?

Comment: @NoOne For example, if I have multiple titles say 'A', 'B','C' and suppose 'A' occurs x times is a day and 'B' occurs y times in a day and 'C' occurs z times in a day. Now I am trying to build a dictionary which will give me all the occurrences for 'A','B' and 'C'. But in the example I am unable to use a ToList() on v => v.Date (feeling stupid again:()

Comment: @Navyseal asking a question is no stupidity at all. I guess you need to ask a seperate question here with a complete example of what you are getting and what you need to get. I am not getting your point here. sorry bro.

Comment: Not a problem. I shall ask a separate question. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
GolfitoDataContext db = new GolfitoDataContext();
var dic = db.GetTable<History>()
        .Select(p => new { p.Title, p.Date }).Where(x => x.Date >= startDateFilter && x.Date <= endDateFilter)
        .DistinctBy(p => p.Title)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .ToDictionary(k => k.Title, v => v.Date);
```

Comment: Feeling stupid but I am facing this issue even after having 

using System.Linq;

'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.

Comment: oops more linq, nuget...got it :)